# VBA Excel - Autofilter multiple filters based on field values in other

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to autofilter a pivot table based on cell values on another worksheet. What would need to happen?
I have 2 values on sheet A (C13 = location and M3 = material)
Based on those 2 values, the pivot table "stock" on sheet B should autofilter accordingly (filter location in cell M1 and filter material in cell M2)

If the values on sheet A are not in the filter (because no data), I should get an empty pivot table (no popup error).

I started off from example code found in this forum but these only included having cell value and filter on the same sheet and only one filter. I keep getting errors when I add another filter.

Thanks for the help!

Started with this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("????")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable 
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim Field2 As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String
Dim NewCat2 As String

Set pt = Worksheets("B").PivotTables("overview")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("location")
NewCat = Worksheets("A").Range("C13").Value


Set pt = Worksheets("B").PivotTables("overview")
Set Field2 = pt.PivotFields("material")
NewCat2 = Worksheets("A").Range("M3").Value
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

With pt
Field2.ClearAllFilters
Field2.CurrentPage = NewCat2
pt.RefreshTable
End With

End Sub
```

Now have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim Field2 As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String
Dim NewCat2 As String

Set KeyCells = Range("T1:T2")

    If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

        Exit Sub
    End If

Set pt = Worksheets("stock").PivotTables("overview")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("location")
With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
End With

Set pt = Worksheets("stock").PivotTables("overview")
Set Field2 = pt.PivotFields("material")
With pt
Field2.ClearAllFilters
End With

Set pt = Worksheets("stock").PivotTables("overview")
NewCat = Worksheets("stock").Range("T1").Value
With pt
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable
End With

Set pt = Worksheets("stock").PivotTables("overview")
NewCat2 = Worksheets("stock").Range("T2").Value
With pt
Field2.CurrentPage = NewCat2
pt.RefreshTable
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I started changing the code and now I'm totally lost
I added the code in the question, but there are loads of mistakes.

Comment: That's okay, write Option Explicit on the top of the module -above private sub, then step through the code with F8. Highlight the lines which are causing errors with comments.

Comment: OK, it got an error in the first line If intersect... (obviously because of the ???), but that's probably where I should define both those variable cells that filter the pivot table. How do I define that? @Lowpar

Comment: ok, it almost works now. I just need to have the cells reference cells on another tab and make sure it works when updating (works when I manually fill in, but not now because it's a formula) @lowpar

Comment: Can you update the code above?

Comment: @Lowpar it's added above, starting from "now have this" (I left the old one as well)